# Setting font size for caption package

Tags: captions, fontsize

I wish to set the font size for caption package, how should I do it, now I have this in my preamble

```
\usepackage[skip=2pt]{caption}
```

Comment: I don't use the caption package, but if you aren't tied to it, you could consider the `boxhandler` package that gives extensive control over caption style and placement.

Answer (score 25):

You can use the `font` key with one of the values `scriptsize`, `footnotesize`, `small`, `normalsize`, `large` or `Large`. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=2pt,font=scriptsize]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{A test caption}
\end{figure}
Some regular text

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want other sizes, you can declare a new format and use \fontsize as in the following (just illustrative) example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=2pt]{caption}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{\fontsize{5}{6}\selectfont#1#2#3}
\captionsetup{format=myformat}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{A test caption}
\end{figure}
Some regular text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  For some reason `normalsize` wasn't working for one of my figures, and the `\DeclareCaptionFormat` variant saved the day!